# FullCalendar jquery plugin: Move events between 2 calendars on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Edit: This is for the FullCalendar jquery plugin(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Is there a way to move an event from one calendar(in month mode) to another calendar(in month mode) that are both on the same page?  I know there is a demo on the fullcalendar home page that shows dragging events onto a calendar, but when you try to drag an event off the calendar onto another calendar, this does not work.  The event gets hidden behind the calendar container element.  Any ideas on how to get something like this to work?  Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information provided / vague. We need to know what the calendar is (ie software used for it) and any code you have tried. If you are not a coder, you will probably have better luck free-lancing this out.

Comment: Sorry, I added the tag but forgot to add it to my post.  This is for the FullCalendar jquery plugin.  Link added to post.  I am a coder, just want to see if anyone out there has done this as it is not built into the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

this issue http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=550, though not yet implemented, will handle this.